# MySQL View doesn't recognize SELECT REPLACE()

Tags: mysql, replace, phpmyadmin, view

I'm officially stumped. I've created a view using this code:

```
ALTER VIEW event_view AS
SELECT 
    '3' School_ID
    , P.post_title 'Short_Description'
    , P.post_content 'Description'
    , E.contact_name 'Contact_Name'
    , P.post_type 'Post_Type'
    , DATE( E.start ) 'Start_Date'
    , TIME( E.start ) 'Start_Time'
FROM cm_3_posts P
LEFT OUTER JOIN cm_3_ai1ec_events E
    ON E.post_ID = P.ID
WHERE P.post_status = 'publish'
    AND P.post_type = 'ai1ec_event' 
    AND E.start > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    AND E.start < NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

However, I want to strip any commas out of the data in the Description field in the view. This query seems like it should work, but when it runs, the results show (in PHPMyAdmin) that the commas are removed, but when I reload the view the commas are back.

```
SELECT REPLACE( Description, ',', '' )
FROM event_view
WHERE Description LIKE '%,%';
```

My question is, how can I permanently remove commas in the Description column's fields in my view? I've tried numerous ways with no success. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line in the view definition that returns the `Description` column (i.e. the `post_content` column.)

Replace this:

```
, P.post_content `Description`
```

With this:

```
, REPLACE(P.post_content, ',', '' ) AS `Description`
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Out of all the things I tried, I can't believe I didn't try that earlier. It seems so obvious now. You rock, and if I had enough cred, I would rate your answer up.